# rearrange int vector c++ function

Tags: c++, function, vector

Hello I have the following std::vector:

```
std::vector<int> source ={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
```

I wanna shuffle it so that for a given number for example n = 4 is the output vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> output = {3,2,1,0,7,6,5,4,11,10,8,9,15,14,13,12}
```

Any ideas how the function should be?

Comment: It doesn't look like a shuffle to me. You want to reverse your elements in groups of `n`? Standard algorithms work on "ranges", not containers, so this should be fairly easy to compose using your existing algorithmic techniques. Play with `std::reverse` and arithmetic operations on integers, then show us what you come up with.

Comment: Unless somebody "clever" answers this.

Comment: @mthe25  How do you get 11,10,8,9 ?:)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Did you mean "arithmetic operations on iterators" rather than "arithmetic operations on integers"?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Hah, yes I did :)

Comment: @LogicStuff With your comment, I'm going to delete my answer! :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Lightness Races in Orbit` said in the comments, it's can be done with standard algorithm functions with a little effort.

```
using vector_size_t = std::vector<int>::size_type;

std::vector<int> source = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
std::vector<int> result = source;

vector_size_t source_size = source.size();
vector_size_t group_size = 4;

for(vector_size_t i = 0; i < source_size / group_size; ++i)
{
    std::reverse
    (
        std::next(std::begin(result), i * group_size),
        std::next(std::begin(result), std::min((i + 1) * group_size, source_size))
    );
}
```

Comment: Not using the proper types in a couple of places but for the given input data this is good enough

Comment: Why `(std::min)` and not just `std::min`?

Comment: Might be better to have `size_t i` rather than `unsigned i`.

Comment: @Muscampester I included `window.h` in VS and `std::min` had conflict with `min` macro in my source. I forget to correct it. Yes It's better to use `size_t`. I'm editing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can it be edited to be better?

Comment: Ah ok, I've seen the round brackets in some libraries where they disambiguate, but I can also see how that might be required in general if macros are involved. The `::size_type` is probably better than `size_t`. TIL. :)